# libneo4j-client cannot close and reopen new session ?

Tags: c++, c, session, neo4j, libneo4j-client

1/ what does a session means for neo4j compared to the connection and particularly for the libneo4j-client C/C++ driver ?

2/ 
I have modified the c code example in https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/ to close the session and restart a new one within the same connection but I got "Failed to Start Session:unexpected error"

Can someone help me to understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

1/ A connection represents the underlying TCP connection to the neo4j server, whereas a session represents a session with the neo4j server, in which state is maintained (such as authentication, open transactions, etc). The initial drafts of the [Bolt Protocol](http://boltprotocol.org) left open the possibility to support multiple sessions over a single TCP connection, but that is not currently supported in any implementation. Unless the protocol specification is updated to support this explicitly, the next major version of libneo4j-client will likely remove the distinction between connection and session.

2/ Best to close the session and the connection concurrently. What you might prefer is to use `neo4j_reset_session` to reset all state in the session, which would be the equivalent of opening a new one.

Comment: @Dan-Abitbol If you could share the modifications you made that resulted in 'unexpected error', that would be interesting. I could only get a 'connection closed' error, which is correct.